# Spacing problem with xpinyin

Tags: spacing, cjk, xpinyin

The `xpinyin` package provides a way to annotate Chinese characters with their Latin phonetic transcriptions. For characters with multiple pronunciations, one would use

```
\xpinyin{<character>}{<pronunciation>}
```

to provide the correct phonetic transcription. However, `\xpinyin` doesn't seem to obey the spacing settings of the `pinyinscope` environment, as illustrated in the following example (notice the overlap of `duan` and `xiang`):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[UTF8]{ctex}
\usepackage{xpinyin}
\xpinyinsetup{multiple={\color{red}}}

\begin{document}
\kaishu  
\begin{pinyinscope}[hsep=1ex]
長短相形，\xpinyin{長}{chang2}短\xpinyin{相}{xiang4}形
\end{pinyinscope}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The problem remains if the option `hsep=1ex` is given when loading the package.

**How to solve this problem?**

Comment: This is a bug of `xpinyin`. We'll fix it soon.

Comment: Before the bug is fixed, you can manually add a `\CJKglue` before `\xpinyin` in the middle of the sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This bug has just been fixed in the new version which was submitted to CTAN. You may update your system in a few days to get it.

**Update:** The new version is available in TeX Live 2013.